# DOJO 1.6 and connecting events on plain HTML components

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

Is it possible to connect events on plain HTML components with DOJO 1.6?

e.g.

```
...
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton">
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton">
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        var radioButtons = dojo.query(".radiobutton", this.domNode);
        var func = dojo.hitch(this, hello());
        dojo.connect(radioButtons[0], "onclick", func);

        function hello(){
            alert("Hello");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling the hello method and hitching the result of the function call.  What you should be doing is hitching to the function.  However, in the example that you posted hitching isn't necessary.

```
var fnHello = function(){
  alert("Hello");
};
// fnHello = dojo.hitch(this, fnHello);
dojo.connect(radioButtons[0], "onclick", fnHello);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/GmE3Q/

Comment: oops...i was working till late last night. saw my mistake today. thanks a million though